# How to set a powershell variable to a specific sharepoint page

Tags: document-library, powershell, security

I have a SharePoint 2010 documents library that contains about 50 .aspx pages.
I want to break inheritance on about 6 pages and set them to specific permissions.

I am able to get a page by numerical index but not by indexing with the page name.  I know I can iterate through all the pages and look for a matching name/title field, but I was wondering if I was missing a way to use the known page name **directly** as an indexer.

For example:

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://website
$web  = $site.RootWeb
$library = $web.Lists["MyPages"]

$page1 = $library.items[0]
$page2 = $library.items[12]
$page3 = $library.items[15]
etc.
```

If page1 is MyPage1.aspx I was looking for a way to get it like this:

```
$page1 = $library.items["MyPage1.aspx"] 
(or something similar).
```

Comment: I did try that, and it didn't work, but now that I look at it closer, all the Titles are empty/null.  I tried to set the title to the value in the DisplayName field (which is MyPage1 for the file MyPage1.aspx) but it says Title is a read-only field.

Comment: Forget my comment. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only one item using the file name without looping all the items you can use CAML.

Here is the script for your case:

```
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$caml ='<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/><Value Type="File">MyPage1.aspx</Value></Eq></Where>'
$query.Query = $caml
$query.RowLimit = 1
$items = $list.GetItems($query)
$item = $items[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The CAML option above works, but I ended up using the Where-Object Operator. I pipe the collection of all pages and pick out the one that matches.

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://website
$web  = $site.RootWeb
$library = $web.Lists["MyPages"]
$pages = $library.items

$page1 = $pages | where { $_.Name -match "MyPage1.aspx"}
$page4 = $pages | where { $_.Name -match "MyPage4.aspx"}

$page1.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
$page4.BreakRoleInheritance($true)

etc.
etc.
```

Comment: Very expensive compared to the CAML, but a bit easier markup :)

Comment: I figured it was probably expensive. The other option I considered for longer term use, was to wrap that CAML into a function in order to improve the mark up.